# Open source machine readable grammar for HTTP/1.1?

Tags: http, grammar, parser-generator, http-1.1

Is there an open source machine-readable grammar for HTTP/1.1 requests and responses? Specifically, i'm looking for a grammar that is accepted by one of the popular parser generators (e.g., ANTLR, CUP, BNFC, ...).

Comment: What about ABNF in RFC 2616 (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Mongrel's grammar](http://github.com/mongrel/mongrel/tree/master/ext/http11/) that uses [ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/). It's [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) and therefore faster.

Answer (score 1):

There's improved (i.e., more exact, less idiomatic, and "pure") ABNF in HTTPbis; see the drafts linked from http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/ or collected at http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/httpbis.abnf